# Exposing additional endpoints through Azure Bot Service

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm creating a proactive bot, that once an endpoint was accessed with the right parameters it will start a new dialog with a specific user.

locally it is easy to be done with `Restify` or `Express`, by just adding a `server.get` method.

How can I do it with the Bot Service?
Is it something I need to change on the `function.json` file?

Comment: Where are you hosting your bot?  You register your bot with Bot Service (which allows channels to talk to it) but the code itself is generally hosted on AWA and is just a webapi app (essentially).

Comment: @CtrlDot It is hosted on Azure Bot Service.
It is actually an azure function, but i can't access the content of the function

Answer (score 1):

refer to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure/azure-bot-service-template-proactive

Using the Azure Bot Service for proactive sample is more complicated to customize, and it adds more services to Azure (more $$). 
I recommend just write your own Bot (Web API); refer to this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages

Answer (score 0):

Azure Bot Service, which is based on Azure Functions, does not support this functionality.

You would need to deploy a BotBuilder SDK bot (using Restify or Express), and then add whatever endpoints you need to your server route configuration.

Comment: What is the recommended method for proactive messaging on Azure Bot Service today? 
A full code example will be wonderful.